# Unable to add httplibrary in robot-framework

Tags: python, eclipse, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I trying to write test scripts using HttpLibrary (from robot framework) on Eclipse and below are the steps I have performed:

- Installed robot framework HttpLibrary using command:

```
    pip install --upgrade robotframework-httplibrary
```

- From Settings-> Imports, added HttpLibrary to my script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library HttpLibrary
```

I am getting the following error:

> ' *init*.py library is absolute, RED prefers using
>   workspace relative paths which makes your projects more portable
>   'httplibrary' library specification file was not generated. try to
>   reload it manually in project explorer'.

Answer (score 1):

According to [HttpLibrary documentation](https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary) the correct way to import the library in your test suite is:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    HttpLibrary.HTTP
```